# How to enter second phone for contact?

Tags: contacts

Just got Oreo and I can only enter 1 phone number in contacts,
how can I get it to record mobile and office?

Comment: To help other visitors, could you specify what Contacts app you're using? And if it's the default app, what phone it's on?

Answer (score 1):

The Contacts app usually contains at least two types of contacts: Contacts stored locally on the phone and those stored on your SIM card.

Local contacts have a large variety of fields and attributes you can set. However if you select a contact from your SIM card you are limited to one phone number and one name per contact entry. This is limited by the SIM card.

Therefore you should make sure you are not creating/editing contacts stored on your SIM card.